# A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name

Tags: azure, arm, azure-web-app-service

When i try to deploy/enable diagnostic settings on Azure Firewall through ARM template. Though i get error.
I'm following [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings-template])

code snippet which i'm using:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {
        "workspaceId": "[Concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/', resourceGroup().name, '/providers/Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces/', 'Fw-LA')]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/diagnosticSettings",
            "apiVersion": "2017-05-01-preview",
            "name": "[concat('FWHM/','Microsoft.Insights/', 'dignostic')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "diagnostic",
                "workspaceId": "[variables('workspaceId')]",
                "logs": [
                    {
                        "category": "AzureFirewallApplicationRule",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "days": 10,
                            "enabled": false
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "metrics": [
                    {
                        "category": "AllMetrics",
                        "enabled": true,
                        "retentionPolicy": {
                            "enabled": false,
                            "days": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you get an error, you should really always include it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this:

```
"type": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/diagnosticSettings",
```

should be this instead:

```
"type": "Microsoft.Network/azureFirewalls/providers/diagnosticSettings",
```

read the article you linked carefully